# Is there way to associate a function to usercontrol

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, .net

Is there way to associate a javascript function to a user control? Lets say I have a name control written in .ascx. Can I define a client side function, lets say `.clear()`, that would be associated to name control. The clear function would clear all the elements of that control. I know I can create clear() javascript function but that would be global javascript function, not necessarily tied to name control. I want to tie the function to name control so that given that I have reference to name object, I should be able to simply call that function from that reference something like:

```
name.clear();
```

I know this can be done using MS Ajax framework but was wondering if I can do something like that using jQuery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If by "clear" you mean set the value of text/password inputs, textareas and select elements to an empty string, and set radio and checkboxes to `!checked`, then you can do something like this:

```
$("#someid").find('select,textarea,input[type="text"],input[type="password"]').val('');
$("#someid").find('input:radio,input:checkbox').prop('checked',false);
```

Or as a plugin:

```
(function( $ ) {
  $.fn.clearChildren = function() {
    this.find('select,textarea,input[type="text"],input[type="password"]').val('');
    this.find('input:radio,input:checkbox').prop('checked',false);
    return this;
  };
})( jQuery );

$("#someid").clearChildren();
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/nnnnnn/AvfUz/

(jQuery does have an ":input" selector that selects all selects, textareas and inputs, but you don't want to set the value of checkboxes and radios so they need to be done separately.)

Comment: I like the plugin option but i am concerned that there is nothing that is tying the clearChildren function  to nameControl.  clearChildren is a global function and can be invoked on any object. Ofcourse i can check within the function that the object that i calling the clearChildren function is a nameControl and not anything else but i was looking at possibility of jQuery level support that can be used to tie a function to a class.

Comment: I don't really understand your concern: why would you want to restrict that type of function to a single control? I guess you could add a method to the corresponding server-side class, such that <%=TheControl.clear()%> would output the appropriate JS. By the way, I forgot to mention in my answer that if your control is an html form element you can just call the built-in .reset() method...

Comment: Thanks nnnnnn for the reply. Here is the reason why i want to restrict the function to single control. Most of the user controls in our team are  created using Ajax framework. They have "clear()" method that clears the contents of those controls. Because Ajax framework allows users to associate a method to control class its easy. You have a Ajax control lets say "Address" that has "clear()" defined for it. When you call <address control reference>.clear(), the code clears the contents of address control.

Comment: The control that i am writing using jQuery needs to provide "clear()" method to clear the contents of my control. If i define a method as you have recommended then for my control it will work fine but then there is no safeguard against this function from being called from a control that this function should not be invoked on.

Answer (score 0):

The user control itself is not rendered as an actual html element, but any of the parts of the user control that's actually rendered as an html element can be referenced from client scripts.

You need to write the control client id to the html from the page or the user control like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    $('#<%= TheControl.ClientID %>').clearChildren();
</script>
```

The jQuery function for clearing the children is defined in @nnnnnn's answer.